# Using .NET SmtpClient to Send mail alters the From name

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have written a method to send mail with attachments and authentication. Everything works perfectly except the `From` email address gets altered in the message received.

For example,

```
foo@example.com
```

Gets changed to,

```
-unknown-@example.com
```

The class I wrote is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;

class Email {

    public MailAddress From { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }


    public Credentials SMTPAuth { get; set; }

    public class Credentials {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public Email() {
        SMTPAuth = new Credentials();
    }

    public List<Attachment> Attachments(params string[] file) {
        List<Attachment> r = new List<Attachment>();
        foreach ( string f in file ) {
            if ( File.Exists( f ) ) {
                r.Add(new Attachment(f));
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public async Task<bool> SendMail( string Subject, string Message, MailAddressCollection To, MailPriority Priority, List<Attachment> Attachments ) {
        bool result = false;
        using ( SmtpClient s=new SmtpClient() ) {
            NetworkCredential auth=new NetworkCredential( SMTPAuth.Username, SMTPAuth.Password );
            s.Host=Host;
            s.Port = Port;
            s.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            s.Credentials=auth;


            using ( MailMessage m=new MailMessage() ) {
                m.From = From;
                m.Subject = Subject;
                m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                m.Priority = Priority;
                m.Body = Message;
                foreach ( MailAddress t in To ) {
                    m.To.Add( t );
                }
                foreach(Attachment a in Attachments) {
                    m.Attachments.Add(a);
                }

                try {
                    await s.SendMailAsync(m);
                    result = true;
                } catch ( SmtpFailedRecipientException ef ) {

                } catch ( SmtpException es ) {

                } catch ( Exception e ) {

                }

            }
            return result;

        }
    }

}
```

And the way I am currently using it (testing), is as follows :

```
    private async void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        Email m = new Email();
        m.SMTPAuth.Username = "foo@example.com";
        m.SMTPAuth.Password="mypassword";
        m.Host = "mail.example.com";
        m.Port = 366;
        m.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("foo@example.com","Company Name - NoReply");

        System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection c = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection();
        c.Add("some.account@gmail.com");

        List<Attachment> a = m.Attachments( @"D:\code.png" );

        bool sent = await m.SendMail( "Testing", "<h1>Hello</h1>", c, System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High, a );
        this.Text = "Message Sent : " + sent.ToString();
    }
```

Mail headers (from message received)

```
From: "Company Name - NoReply" <-unknown-@example.com>
To: example@gmail.com, support@example.com
Reply-To: "Company Name - NoReply" <noreply@example.com>
X-Priority: 1
Priority: urgent
Importance: high
Date: 1 May 2015 21:15:29 -0400
Subject: Testing
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary=--boundary_0_7310d152-dff2-4139-9db1-2558b3e70e73
X-ACL-Warn: {
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - mail.example.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - example.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: mail.example.com: acl_c_relayhosts_text_entry: -unknown-@example.com|example.com
X-From-Rewrite: rewritten was: [noreply@example.com], actual sender does not match
```

How can I prevent it from changing the string preceding the @ symbol in my from email address to `-unknown-` ? -- and why is it doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Send(string email, string subject, string body)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_Host, _Port);
        client.Timeout = _Timeout;
        client.EnableSsl = _Ssl;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_Username, _Password);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("No Reply <noreply@mysite.com>", email, subject, body);
        message.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        message.Sender = new MailAddress("noreply@mysite.com", "No Reply");
        lock (this)
        {
            for (var count = 0; count < _MaxTryCount; ++count)
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                    return;
                }
                catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                catch (SmtpException)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(_Timeout);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So this line >  message.Sender = new MailAddress("noreply@mysite.com", "No Reply"); <  is the proper way to assign the from address ?

Comment: I have used this method of sending an email and it works for me. Try it.

Comment: I tried adding the line for .Sender, and still get the same issue.  I can't use the ctor method as their are multiple 'To's.  This is quite strange that it is messing with the From address in this manner when it is being set correctly.  My message gets delivered. The only thing being messed up is the first segment of the from email address itself.

Comment: Your SMTP server may have some rules about emails going thru.

Comment: I am in control of the SMTP server.  Mail goes through just fine, even from Outlook, or PHP scripts using (requires) authentication. I have it configured to require full email address + pass for auth.  Did notice some peculiar X headers in the received message, added to original message.

Comment: Just to clarify,  the authentication email is the same as the email used for from address. (and no duh google.....  `-unknown-@example.com` does not match `noreply@example.com` .